# Exercise about Zariski-topology

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to became familiar with the basic notions of algebraic geometry and I proved the fact which states every continuous mapping from $\mathbb R^n$ with the Zariski topology to $\mathbb R$ with the usual topology have to be constant in the following way.

Let be $a$ an element of the image of $f$. For every $\epsilon>0$ the preimage of the open interval $(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)$ is dense in $\mathbb R^n$, so the preimage of its closure is the whole space.It means that for every $P\in\mathbb R^n$ $f(P)\in [a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon]$ for every $\epsilon>0$ that is $f(P)$ is contained by the set $ \{a\} =\cap_{\epsilon>0}[a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon]$, quod erat demonstrandum.

My question is, is there an else proof of this fact using other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another proof:

Suppose $x,y$ are two distinct points in the image and let $I,J$ be disjoint open intervals containing them. Then $f^{-1}(I\cup J)$ must be open and disconnected, thus being the union of two disjoint, nonempty open sets. However, there do not exist two disjoint, nonempty open sets, which is a contradiction.